# Странная работа continue в цикле while

Tags: c++, c, циклы, while, continue

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;

    do {
        printf("%d", i++);
        if(i == 1) continue;
    } while(i == 0);
}
```

Почему программа выводит только `0`, а не `01`?

Comment: вы выводите исходное значение переменной. Сразу после постинкремента, его значение не нулевое, и цикл прекращается

Comment: @ARHovsepyan почему прекращается если я явно указал при единице продолжать?!

Comment: а в продолжении выполняется:  если  `i != 0` то прекратить. А у вас уже `i == 1` .   if(i == 1) continue; совершенно ни на что не влияет

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`continue` не пропускает условие цикла, а только оставшуюся часть тела.

У вас после него в теле ничего нет, поэтому оно ни на что не влияет.

Comment: То есть исполнение прыгает вниз а не вверх как в цикле for?!

Comment: просто пропускает тело до конца цикла. А где именно условие - дело десятое

Comment: короче это баг понятно раз не смотрит где условие

Comment: это не баг. это очевидное поведение. Возможно, Вы читали книги, которые писали, что это прыжок в начало. Ну так, это было упрощение.

Comment: @бог *"короче это баг"* Очень смелое заявляение. *"прыгает вниз а не вверх как в цикле for"* А откуда вы знаете, что в `for` он прыгает не вниз? Может он к закрывающей фигурной скобке прыгает?

Answer (score 3):

Для инструкции `continue` стандарт дает не двусмысленное объяснение для каждого из циклов:

> The continue statement shall occur only in an iteration-statement and
> causes control to pass to the loopcontinuation portion of the smallest
> enclosing iteration-statement, that is, **to the end of the loop**.
> More precisely, in each of the statements
>
> ```
> while (foo) {       do {               for (;;){
>   {                   {                 {
>     // ...              // ...            // ...
>   }                   }                 }
> contin: ;           contin: ;          contin: ;
> }                   } while(foo)       }
> ```
>
> a continue not contained in an enclosed iteration statement is
> equivalent to `goto contin`.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.cont

Comment: @Tocic я специально не стал давать эту ссылку, потому что там форматирование поехавшее. )))

Answer (score 1):

мы вначале попадаем в блок do. там вызывается

```
printf("%d", i++);
```

так как изначально i = 0; печатается: "0", а затем только увеличивается.

после printf у нас i = 1;
дальше пытаемся перейти на следующую итерацию. но так как в условии:

```
while(i == 0);
```

выходим из цикла. Поэтому да, напечатается только один раз

Comment: Строку с continue вы проигнорировали???

Comment: так за ней ничего не последует. цикл перейдет на следующую итерацию, где провериться условие while(i == 0);

Comment: Следующая итерация начинается с printf а не с while!

Comment: следующая итерация не начнется, так как условие , при которой итерация должна начаться будет false

Comment: напиши while(i < 2) и строку "if(i == 1) continue;" удали)